# Elixir: clone a list idiomatically

Tags: list, copy, elixir

I can always do something like this:

```elixir
new_list = Enum.map(old_list, fn x -> x end)
```

There is a dozen more equally, or marginally less ugly, ways of doing so, of course. Somehow, I can't find an idiomatic way of copying a list. There certainly must be a way.

Comment: What do you want to achieve by "cloning" a list? In which way would the cloned list behave differently from the original?

Answer (score 8):

Elixir is an immutable language, so the idiomatic way is this:

```elixir
clone = original
```

There is no need to "clone". The data assigned to existing variables cannot be edited, so assigning one variable to another conceptually results in a copy of the data. You cannot edit existing data - if you reassign to an existing variable, you are conceptually pointing that variable at a new data-structure.

```elixir
original = [1, 2, 3] |> IO.inspect(label: "original")
clone = original |> IO.inspect(label: "clone")
prepended = [0 | original] |> IO.inspect(label: "prepended")
original |> IO.inspect(label: "original again")
original = [5, 6, 7] |> IO.inspect(label: "original rebound")
clone |> IO.inspect(label: "clone again")
```

Output:

```elixir
original: [1, 2, 3]
clone: [1, 2, 3]
prepended: [0, 1, 2, 3]
original again: [1, 2, 3]
original rebound: [5, 6, 7]
clone again: [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 2):

Since data structures in Elixir are immutable, I can't think of a reason you'd ever need to "clone" a list. It would do nothing. That being said, if you're looking for a way to do that exact nothing, you could reach for [`Enum.to_list/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#to_list/1).

```
iex> Enum.to_list([1, 2, 3])
[1, 2, 3]
```